# How to make an IDE-independent commit

Tags: svn, architecture, ide

Checking my projects' folder in the SVN Repository, I can see many files and configurations related to the IDE used in this project.

For example, the folder structure of a JavaScript project created on NetBeans may look like this, containing a `nbproject` and `config` folder, and the actual source code inside `public_html`:

[image: NetBeans folder structure]

While a JavaScript project created on Eclipse will have the following structure, containing a `.settings` folder, a `.project` file and the actual source code in the root:

[image]

My question is, is there a way to make commits containing just the source-code in the root of the project's folder, without any IDE-related file? Is this even a good practice?

My point of view is that this would make IDE migration simpler and the project IDE-independent, having developers working with their IDE of choice. Is this valid?

Comment: Use the [`svn:ignore`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html) property to exclude files and directories generated by your build toolchain.

Comment: Seems a good approach. In the case of NetBeans, where the source code root is not the actual project's root, how should I proceed then? Should I share to the repository just the `public_html` folder?

Comment: Yep, that's what I would do. In general, the only thing you should be maintaining in your repo is the source code and other files that *you (and your team) write*. No IDE settings, no external libraries, etc.

Comment: I have the same opinion. I am refactoring the projects' folders in the repository to contain only the source codes, no IDE settings. Thanks for the tips.